# Flask Error: Unable to predict the result

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

I have created an html template to predict the values but not able to do that. I do not know much about `flask`, but trying to start with. Can you help me do resolve the issue?

Relevant parts of my code are as follows:

I am unable to predict the value

```
    from __future__ import division, print_function
    import sys
    import os
    import glob
    import re
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow.keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
    
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
    app = Flask(__name__)
    MODEL_PATH ='model_resnet50.h5'
    model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
    
    def model_predict(img_path, model):
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x=x/255
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        preds = model.predict(x)
        preds=np.argmax(preds, axis=1)
        if preds==0:
            preds="Dhoni"
        elif preds==1:
            preds="Kohli"
        else:
            preds="Rohith"
        return preds
    
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        # Main page
        return render_template('index.html')
    @app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            f = request.files['file']
            basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
            file_path = os.path.join(
                basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
            f.save(file_path)
            preds = model_predict(file_path, model)
            result=preds
            return result
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

my `index.html`

This is my `index.html`. Please help me to resolve the issue

```
    <h2>Predict Image</h2>
    
    <div>
        <form id="upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="imageUpload" class="upload-label">
                Choose...
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
        </form>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="btn-predict">Predict!</button>
        </div>
        <h3 id="result">
           <span> </span>
        </h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: you don't have `action="/predict"` in `<form>` so it sends to `/` because it was load from `/`

Comment: to send `<form>` you have put `<button>` inside `<form>`

Comment: `upload()` should generate text or HTML even when `request.method` is `GET` - or remove `GET` from `methods=[...]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have model to test code in main file but HTML need changes.

To send `<form>` you have to put `<button>` inside `<form>`. And it should have `type="submit"`

You load `index.html` in `/` so it automatically sends `<form>` to `/`. You need `action="/predict"` to send `<form>` to `/predict`.

```
<form action="/predict" id="upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label for="imageUpload" class="upload-label">
            Choose...
        </label>

        <input type="file" name="file" id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">

        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="btn-predict">Predict!</button>
        </div>

</form>
```